Why can't one define a complete statistic from a minimal sufficient one by accounting for all first-order ancillaries?
According to this: "If a minimal sufficient statistic $T$ is not complete, then there is a non-trivial first order ancillary statistic $V(T)$, and there does not exist any complete statistic." In the case of the Pearson correlation, for example, $r(X, Y)$ is minimal sufficient under bivariate normality, but either $X$ or $Y$ is ancillary, so $r$ is not complete minimal sufficient.
Why is it we cannot construct a complete statistic from an incomplete minimal sufficient statistic, just by conditioning on any first-order ancillaries? My intuition is that this is because one cannot always condition on all ancillaries simultaneously. For example, both $X$ and $Y$ are individually ancillary for Pearson's r under bivariate normality, but $(X, Y)$ is clearly a sufficient statistic. That makes sense in the case of $r$ but is it the answer generally?
